# Arreglos de caracteres, añadir y quitar

Tags: java

tengo una duda, tengo que hacer un programa que haga que el usuario ingrese un string y 2 números; tengo que volverlo un array de caracteres y hacer que imprima: el string sin la parte especificada.
Ejemplo:
Se ingresa perro, y los números 1 y 2, imprime pro.
Y el otro es hacer que imprima directamente después lo enumerado.
Ejemplo: 
Se ingresa perro, y los números 1 y 2, se imprime pererro.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, se lo agradecería un montón >_< !

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte tienes que poner el código que haz intentado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a StackOverflow .
Ya que has pedido como seria con arrays de caracteres esta seria una simple solucion:

```
        // Datos de ejemplo
   String ejemplo ="perro";
   int num1 = 1;
   int num2=2;
   String resultado="";
   // Convierto el string que me mandan a un array de chars
   char[] array = ejemplo.toCharArray();
   // Recorro el array
   for (int i =0;i<array.length;i++){
       // Filtro por las posiciones que me mandan
        if (i!=num1 && i!=num2){
       // Concateno los chars filtrados correctamente
        resultado+=array[i];
       }
   }
    System.out.println(resultado);
```

A partir de esto no tendria que costarte sacar la segunda parte que pides.
Un saludo, por favor para la proxima adjunta el codigo que has realizado para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion substring

*Para el primer ejercicio :

```
   `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String p =scan.next();
    int a,b;
    a=scan.nextInt();
    b=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(p.substring(0, a)+p.substring(b+1));`
```

*Para el segundo :

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String p =scan.next();
    int a,b;
    a=scan.nextInt();
    b=scan.nextInt();
    String s = p.substring(a,b+1);
    System.out.println(p.substring(0,a)+s+s+p.substring(b+1));
```

Espero que te sea util